# Create Image from running instance will change the public IP address?

Tags: amazon-ec2

As far as I know, if you create an image from a running instance, it would by default reboot the instance. Do correct me if I am wrong on this.

For my situation, my free elastic ip are all used up and I need to do some heavy modification on the instance operating system. Before proceeding with those modifications, I would like to at least do a complete backup on everything. Which means I need to create an AMI and do snapshot on the EBS before proceeding. Problem is, I can't afford to lose the public and private IP address of that instance because it would take me more work to update all other softwares in different servers that would connect to it (unless of course if I mess it up and had to use the backup created AMI image after all).

So my questions are:

1. If I just simply create an image from that instance that is still running without stopping it. It will reboot by default, but would it change it's public and private IP addresses? I noticed that a normal "reboot" when you right click the instance does not change those IP address. Is it the same kind of "reboot" when you create image without stopping the instance?
2. Is it safer that I stop the instance first before creating an image or creating the image while it's running is safe enough? Consider data integrity.

Thank you

Comment: By the way, you can select the `no-reboot` option when creating an image. From [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html#process-creating-an-ami-ebs): "Amazon EC2 powers down the instance before creating the AMI to ensure that everything on the instance is stopped and in a consistent state during the creation process. If you're confident that your instance is in a consistent state appropriate for AMI creation, you can tell Amazon EC2 not to power down and reboot the instance. "

Comment: Yeah. That I know. I’m more concern of those things that I asked on the IP address part. Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 0):

The default reboot during AMI creation will just do a normal reboot. It will not change IP addresses.

The **Private IP address** will *never* change.

The **Public IP address** *might* change if the instance is stopped.

Best practice is to either use an Elastic IP address (free if attached to a running instance, and you can request more if you need them) or use a DNS Name that resolves to an IP address. That way, if the IP address changes, simple update the DNS entry without needing to change any references.